# Change border colors when button is clicked

Tags: javascript, html, css

Hi so im trying to make it so when one button is clicked the border color is changed to blue and all the other button border color is changed to orange. my problem is, it's not working the border color for other button is not changing.

```js
function clickimageone(el){
 el.style.border = "1px solid blue";
 document.getElementById("border2").className="borderorange";
}
```

```css
.border1{
 border: 1px solid red;
}
.border2{
 border: 1px solid red;
}
.bordeorange{
 border: 1px solid orange;
}
```

```html
<div class="image"><img src="img/500.png" onclick="clickimageone(this)" class="border1" style="height: 500px; max-height: 150px; max-width: 300px; top: 50px; left: 50px"></div>
<div class="image"><img src="img/1000.png" onclick="clickimagetwo(this)" class="border2" style="height: 500px; max-height: 150px; max-width: 300px; top: 50px; left: 100px"></div>
```

so basically what im asking is when one button is clicked the border of that button is changing to blue and all the other button color will change to orange.

Comment: @vladimir830 it doesn't work

Comment: Check my answer please

Answer (score 1):

Change `class` to `id` so that `document.getElementById()` works fine

Here's working code:

```js
function clickimageone(el){
 el.style.border = "1px solid blue";
 document.getElementById("border2").style.border = "1px solid orange";
}

function clickimagetwo(el){
 el.style.border = "1px solid blue";
 document.getElementById("border1").style.border = "1px solid orange";
}
```

```css
#border1{
 border: 1px solid red;
}
#border2{
 border: 1px solid red;
}
.bordeorange{
 border: 1px solid orange;
}
```

```html
<div class="image"><img src="img/500.png" onclick="clickimageone(this)" id="border1" style="height: 500px; max-height: 150px; max-width: 300px; top: 50px; left: 50px"></div>
<div class="image"><img src="img/1000.png" onclick="clickimagetwo(this)" id="border2" style="height: 500px; max-height: 150px; max-width: 300px; top: 50px; left: 100px"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just modify the getElementById to `querySelector('.border2')`, the 
 `border2` is not a id, but a class.